# Python - Django for realtime webapp

Tags: python, django, node.js, tornado, gevent

I need to develop a realtime webapp (Tic Tac Toe) that allow multiple players to play against each other in realtime. The webapp will have some traffic, and will be used in the real world. I will need also to store all classifications in a MySQL ou PostgreSQL database and I need to register users and handle sessions.

I've read some about the subject, but I have some doubts.

For this kind of project I will have to use in combination with Django an asynchronous networking library like Tornado, Gevent or Node.js.

1 - My first question is, It will be possible to get the Django user session in a Tornado/Gevent/Node.js process?

2- Which one of this libraries(Tornado/Gevent/Node.js) should I use for this kind of project?

Best Regards,

Comment: First question should be separated as a new post.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question, [gevent-socketio](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio) is nicely integrated with Django, so if you run your Django site from Gevent you will have access to the session.

Please note that the session will only be passed at the socket creation though, then you're on your own.